# TFS Can't Search On Repro Steps Or History

Tags: tfs

I can't get a TFS query that searches on Repro Steps or History to work. We're using the Visual Studio Scrum 1.0 template....not sure if that has anything to do with it.

If I simply create a query:

```
Repro Steps Contains a
```

I get 0 results.

Conversely, if I do

```
Repro Steps Does Not Contain a
```

I get all bugs in the entire system as a result (including ones that have the letter a in the Steps to Reproduce).

Same results when searching on the History field.

Comment: How can I tell? I'm using the query wizard in VS...

Comment: Open the query editor in VS. From the menu File -> Save as. Save it on local disk. Open the file in notepad

Answer (score 4):

When you query your work items, the query is transformed into an SQL statement that is executed on SQL Server. When you have Full Text Search (FTS) enabled on your SQL Server, then we will use that for the sake of performance. The downside however of FTS is that the it only can find whole words, and not part of words.

If you want to query on partial words, then [uninstall FTS on your SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143412.aspx). The query that is exected on SQL is now using the LIKE '%a%' oeperation, and the LIKE operator will search on partial words. The downside is that a LIKE operator is always performing a table scan.

If you only have a few thousand work items, you should not see a lot of difference in the performance.

Comment: Thanks so much for your follow up and assistance in getting this resolved Ewald. It's much appreciated.

Comment: I tried disabling the daemon service for FTS but the problem persists...any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ewald, I'm a bit disappointed that I need to perform major maintenance on the server to do this. I certainly hope this operation does not hose my server.

Answer (score 2):

Experimented with the query you provide `Repro Steps Contains a` I got the same results you do.
 I then placed `Repro Steps Contains start` and it did work correctly.
I then placed `Repro Steps Contains tart` and got back 0 results.

That leads me to conclude that TFS WIQL operates on a 'word' basis when clause is checked with "Contains"/"Does not Contain".

There are Bugs containing an `a` as a standalone word in our WI-store, so this 'word' basis is also considering a minimum length.

Comment: Nothing I 'm aware of. On the other hand, quering with `Contains a` doesn't seem very usefull to me either.

Comment: Contains a certainly isn't useful. However a Contains "MyDatabasePrefix" is what we're trying to do. We have lots of DBs and they're all named MyDatabasePrefixClientNameDate. We want to find all bugs that reference a database name.

Comment: I think you are at a loss here, see also http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/3a191e7b-5348-498d-aaa9-b26ceb98f28d

Comment: That was in 2007. Is this still true?

Answer (score 0):

I am the Program Manager from the TFS Product Team responsible for the Work Item search. I have tried to repro it on a standard TFS 2010 machine, but I was unable to reproduce your situation.

What TFS version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for replying. We're using TFS 2010 with the Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 1.0 template. I'm searching on the field "Repro Steps", which seems to correspond with the "Steps to Reproduce" field in the bug template. I'd be glad to provide whatever additional information you need.

Comment: Could you please send me a an export of your work items (via Excel) you want to search on and the query you are using, so I can do som further investigation? You can send it to v-ewald_at_hotmail_dot_com

Comment: Sent, please let me know if you need any more info. Thanks.